# Does the Ne10 FFT implementation work on both Arm 32-bit `armv7l` and 64-bit `aarch64`?

Tags: c, arm, fft, neon

I'm using [Cortex-A53](https://developer.arm.com/Processors/Cortex-A53) processor for a C code project.

The project needs a Fourier transform, for which planned to use the [Ne10](https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10/) library.

The Cortex-A53 processor can work in two modes: as 32-bit `armv7l` or 64-bit `aarch64`.

Will the [Ne10 FFT](https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10/tree/master/modules/dsp) implementation work on both `armv7l` and `aarch64`?

Comment: no. The assembly codes are written for `aarch32` only

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Jake, thanks. Is there a FFT optimized for `aarch64`? Overall, what do you think is currently the best solution for FFT on `aarch64`?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Could you please comment on [Ne10: NEON optimized for both AArch32 and AArch64](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/operating-systems-blog/posts/ne10-fft-feature)?

Comment: NE10 does have f32 reel fft for `aarch64`, but nothing else. What's your desired forma? int16? reel or complex?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE I need real FFT for float 32 for `aarch64`. My input is audio, 1D.